# Report Viewer Errors on PDF export with embedded image

Tags: vb.net, reporting, reportviewer, reportviewer2008

I have one program out of 15 that will not export a report to PDF.  If I remove the embedded image it exports.  It appears this is related to the embedded image.  I get the error:

```
"Export Error":
An Error occurred during local report processing.
An error occurred during rendering of the report.
An error occurred during rendering of the report.
Non-negative number required
Parameter name: value
```

It WILL export to excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Image was corrupt.  I deleted the image from embedded images, and deleted the jpeg used.  I then embedded a new image, and added it to the report... No issues.